# I have to map a composed array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array I need to get all the tasks that have the same record Id in an array

```
workspaces=[{recordId:1,tasks:[{title:'me'},{title:'we'}]},{recordId:2,tasks:[{title:'hi'},{title:'it'}]},{recordId:1,tasks:[{title:'they',{title:'she'}]}]
```

the final result will be like:`[[recordId:1,tasks:[{title:'me'},{title:'we'},{title:'they',{title:'she'}]],[recordId:2,tasks:[{title:'hi'},{title:'it'}]]]`
i used groupBy from lodash but i did get a separate arrays anyone have any idea how to implement that.

Comment: Your "final result" is not valid syntax. Did you mean `[{recordId: 1, tasks: ...}, {recordId: 2, tasks: ...}]`?

Comment: @Maria-Elena Which doesn't make a ton of sense to me as the desired output. Can you give the exact output you're looking for, or maybe a reason as to why you need an array of arrays?

Comment: arrays can not have properties in literal notation. please add a valid result, as well as without the error behind `{title:'they'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be a two step approach by

- collecting items for a certain group
- render the array in the wanted format.

This approach features a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and uses [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for getting the wanted result.

```js
var workspaces = [{ recordId: 1, tasks: [{ title: 'me' }, { title: 'we' }] }, { recordId: 2, tasks: [{ title: 'hi' }, { title: 'it' }] }, { recordId: 1, tasks: [{ title: 'they' }, { title: 'she' }] }],
    grouped = Array.from(
        workspaces.reduce((m, { recordId, tasks }) =>
            m.set(recordId, [...(m.get(recordId) || []), ...tasks]), new Map),
        ([recordId, tasks]) => ({ recordId, tasks })
    );
   
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but OP said desired output is "array of arrays"

Comment: i see no array of arrays in the question.

Comment: It's in the title as well as the OP's comment on the question: "the result should be an array of arrays"

Comment: what is wrong with this answer, despite of the *array in array* problem?

Comment: @mhodges, either way, op has not added a valid result. this answer uses the earlier edition of the wanted result.

Comment: even if this is not the wanted format, any approach to a solution is worth to post, according to meta (please search yourself).

Comment: I still don't see it as useful, so I chose to downvote it. If I thought it was not an answer, or the answer had serious content issues, I would have flagged it for removal.

Answer (score 1):

Nina Scholz solution is more sophisticated, but harder to read.
You can achieve the same like this:

```js
const workspaces= [
  {recordId: 1, tasks: [{title:'me'}, {title:'we'}] },
  {recordId: 2, tasks: [{title:'hi'}, {title:'it'}] },
  {recordId: 1, tasks: [{title:'they'}, {title:'she'}] }
]
const workspacesById = []
workspaces.forEach(w => {
  const idx = workspacesById.findIndex(item => item.recordId === w.recordId)
  if (idx > -1) {
    workspacesById[idx].tasks = [...workspacesById[idx].tasks, ...w.tasks]
  } else {
    workspacesById.push(w)
  }
})
console.log(workspacesById)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is close to what you want

```js
const arr = [
  { recordId: 1, tasks: [{ title: 'me' }, { title: 'we' }] },
  { recordId: 2, tasks: [{ title: 'hi' }, { title: 'it' }] },
  { recordId: 2, tasks: [{ title: 'f' }, { title: 'e' }] },
  { recordId: 2, tasks: [{ title: 'hi' }, { title: 'it' }] },
];

const result = arr.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (result[item.recordId]) {
    const prevTasks = result[item.recordId];
    result[item.recordId].tasks = prevTasks.concat(item.tasks);
  } else {
    result[item.recordId] = item.tasks;
  }
  return result;
}, {});
```

The result will be

```js
{
  "1": [
    {
      "title": "me"
    },
    {
      "title": "we"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "title": "hi"
    },
    {
      "title": "it"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: According to the OP, the output should be an array of arrays.

Comment: I think you tagged the wrong person. I haven't posted a solution yet, because we haven't gotten clarification from the OP on the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your result

```
let result = [];
for(let i=0; i<workspaces.length; i++) {
    let recordFound = false;
    if (result.length > 0) {
        for(let j=0; j<result.length ; j++) {
            if(workspaces[i].recordId === result[j].recordId) {
                result[j].tasks = [...result[j].tasks, ...workspaces[i].tasks];
                recordFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!recordFound) {
        result.push(workspaces[i]);
    }
}
console.log(result); //your expected result
```